# How to provide a link to a shared network folder on windows using php+html?

Tags: php, html

I have installed Apache Server(windows) on one of my network computer say machine1 along with MySql database. In one of the web page, I am providing a intranetwork path like "\\resultserver\abc\new.txt" as  where "resultserver" is another machine say machine2 on the intranet.

Now the problem that I am facing is....when I am opening the webpage from any machine say machine "X" on the intranet....the above link doesn't work. It acts as a dead link in IE and in Firefox, its saying "The requested URL /\\resultserver\abc\new.txt was not found on this server." 
Same thing when I am trying to do from the machine1 (having Apache+ MySql), the above link works.

Please help..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not reliably. Most web browsers do not allow web pages cannot link to local files.

If they did, the link would need to be specified using the `file://` protocol. (But, again, most browsers do not allow this.)